# mysql logs showing status information after data restore with innobackupex

Tags: mysql, database, percona, innobackupex

After database restore with innobackupex, we are seeing MySQL coming up clean but the logs are showing status info on buffers and locks. Is this a OK sign or is there any inconsistency/error?. db in use is MySQL server version 5.5.33.

mysqld.log showing below info

141205  7:19:02 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
141205  7:19:02 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.33-log'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Status information:

Current dir: /var/db/data/
Running threads: 0  Stack size: 262144
Current locks:
lock: 0x1785f540:

lock: 0x178540c0:

lock: 0x17849490:

lock: 0x17836f70:

lock: 0x1783bb90:

lock: 0x17825a80:

lock: 0x178207c0:

lock: 0x1781a280:

lock: 0x17812040:

lock: 0xf32fa0:

lock: 0xf33780:

lock: 0xf336a0:

lock: 0xf335c0:

lock: 0xf33160:

lock: 0xf33080:

lock: 0xf32ec0:

lock: 0xf32de0:

lock: 0xf32d00:

lock: 0xf33860:

lock: 0xf33240:

lock: 0xf334e0:

lock: 0xf33400:

lock: 0xf33320:

lock: 0xf32c20:

lock: 0xf32b40:

lock: 0xf32a60:

Key caches:
default
Buffer_size:     209715200
Block_size:           1024
Division_limit:        100
Age_limit:             300
blocks used:             0
not flushed:             0
w_requests:              0
writes:                  0
r_requests:              0
reads:                   0

handler status:
read_key:            0
read_next:           0
read_rnd             0
read_first:          3
write:               0
delete               0
update:              0

Table status:
Opened tables:         16
Open tables:            9
Open files:            19
Open streams:           0

Alarm status:
Active alarms:   0
Max used alarms: 0
Next alarm time: 0

Memory status:
Non-mmapped space allocated from system: 363499520
Number of free chunks:                   12
Number of fastbin blocks:                18
Number of mmapped regions:               18
Space in mmapped regions:                685850624
Maximum total allocated space:           0
Space available in freed fastbin blocks: 1584
Total allocated space:                   363367408
Total free space:                        132112
Top-most, releasable space:              115152
Estimated memory (with thread stack):    1049350144

Events status:
LLA = Last Locked At  LUA = Last Unlocked At
WOC = Waiting On Condition  DL = Data Locked

Event scheduler status:
State      : INITIALIZED
Thread id  : 0
LLA        : n/a:0
LUA        : n/a:0
WOC        : NO
Workers    : 0
Executed   : 0
Data locked: NO

Event queue status:
Element count   : 0
Data locked     : NO
Attempting lock : NO
LLA             : init_queue:139
LUA             : init_queue:149
WOC             : NO
Next activation : never

Thanks in advance